# while loop inside an array?

Tags: php, arrays, while-loop

I'm trying to figure out if I'm able to do a while loop inside an array

```
while($row = $retail -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){

$json['data'][] = array(

'id'=>$row['idretailers'],
"category"=>$row['category'],
"headline"=>$row['headline'],
'price'=> array ("full_price" => $row['price']),
'description'=>$row['description'],
"comments" => array(
while($row_c = $comments -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){

 // more items  
})
);
}
```

There's a while loop within the comments, is that possible?

Thanks!

Comment: simply try it, see that you'll get a syntax error and try a different approach. Short: no it's not possible.

Comment: @Khurram Is that a Schrödinger reference?

Comment: @deceze it came from my own sense of understanding :-D, i didn't know about that great scientist before, thx for sharing his name and thx to wiki , cheers

Comment: @JohnConde I did try it. I ment to ask which approach should I take to accomplish something similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are inserting it into a JSON String, do it like this:

```
while($row = $retail -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){

    $json['data'][] = array(

        "id"=>$row['idretailers'],
        "category"=>$row['category'],
        "headline"=>$row['headline'],
        "price"=> array ("full_price" => $row['price']),
        "description"=>$row['description'],
        "comments" => $comments->fetchAll()
    );
}
```

Otherwise, you could call [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) on the comments:

```
while($row = $retail -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){

    $json['data'][] = array(

        "id"=>$row['idretailers'],
        "category"=>$row['category'],
        "headline"=>$row['headline'],
        "price"=> array ("full_price" => $row['price']),
        "description"=>$row['description'],
        "comments" => implode("\n", $comments->fetchAll());
    );
}
```

Comment: +1 and answer for full script of example, and other method approach

Answer (score 2):

The way you write it is not possible, but there is a simple solution:

```
"comments" => $comments -> fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)
```